# configure file is missing in libxml2

Tags: git, libxml2

I pulled libxml2 library using git command "git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2" . As per README file instructions , I have to run "./configuration" first. But i could not find the configure file. what could be the issue? I am using RHEL6 machine.

source :http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 3):

To create the `configure` (not `configuration`) script, you need the GNU `autoconf` tool.

Comment: so first i have to run autoconf to generate the configure file ?

Comment: Yes. See [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Making-configure-Scripts) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably download the latest official release from the [FTP server](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/). Releases ship with the `configure` script.

If you really want to build a Git checkout, you have to install GNU Autoconf and create the configure script by running `sh autogen.sh` in the libxml2 source directory.